# Including third party libs on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, classpath

I would like to include some libs in our Apache Tomcat for development, but just copying and paste in the lib folder of Tomcat doesn't work.

How can I do that? I haven't found the documentation about this.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout

Comment: I want the lib shared across all webapps.

Comment: @MartinK  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Shared_Library_Files is just paste and copy?

Comment: You might want to bounce Tomcat after placing new libraries into the lib directory.

Comment: "Should" work (did you restart tomcat btw.?). Can you be a bit more specific about your tc. installation? E.g. Did you install it using some package manager (yum, apt-get,etc), or are you using it as downloaded from tomcat.apache.org? Which tomcat version are you referring to (assuming 7.27)?

Comment: @MartinK you answered the link I was looking for. It's a normal unzipped tomcat. I'll investigate here. Thanks